# Log4j2 LoggerContext Not Updating

Tags: java, log4j2

I have created a custom appender (*WAppender*) and a filter (*WFilter*) that I want to add during runtime.
Adding them to the current `Configuration` seems to work just fine, but calling `updateLoggers()` does not have an effect on the `LoggerContext`.

The inital configuration is loaded from the *log4j2.xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="logging.WFilter, logging.WAppender" status="warn">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">log</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %p - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <File name="file-log" fileName="logs/app.log" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %p - %m%n"/>
        </File>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file-log" level="error"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Then, I attempt to modify the configuration as described in  [Programmatically Modifying the Current Configuration after Initialization](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent).

```
private static final LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
private static final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
```

```
public static void attatchAppender (AppenderData appenderData) {

        if (appenderData != null) {

            WAppender appender = appenderData.getAppender();
            WFilter filter = appenderData.getFilter();

            appender.start();
            config.addAppender(appender);

            AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(appender.getName(), Level.DEBUG, filter);
            AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
            LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, Level.DEBUG,
                    "org.apache.logging.log4j", "true", refs, null, config, filter);

            loggerConfig.addFilter(filter);
            loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, Level.DEBUG, filter);
            config.addLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", loggerConfig);

            context.updateLoggers();
            // context.updateLoggers(config); (does not work either)

            Map<String, Appender> map = config.getAppenders();
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(map.get(key).getName());
            }

            /*
            * Outputs:
            *   console-log
            *   file-log
            *   wLogger-0 (as expected)
            */

            for (Logger logger : context.getLoggers()) {
                map = logger.getAppenders();
                for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(map.get(key).getName());
                }
            }

            /*
             * Outputs:
             *   console-log
             *   file-log
             *
             *   console-log
             *   file-log
             */


        }
```

As shown in the code, the `Configuration` does include the newly added *wLogger-0* but the `Context` does not.

PS. Both *WAppender* and *WFilter* have been tested and they work (initalised from the configuration file).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work by getting the `RootLogger` and its `Configuration` instead and adding both the *WAppender* and *WFilter* to it, and then updating the Loggers with the new `Configuration`.

I was probably missing something on the inner workings of Log4j.

This adds the appender to all loggers which is what I wanted to achieve anyway.

```
    public static void attatchAppender (AppenderData appenderData) {

        if (appenderData != null) {

            WAppender appender = appenderData.getAppender();
            WFilter filter = appenderData.getFilter();

            Logger rootLogger = context.getRootLogger();
            LoggerConfig rootLoggerConfig = config.getRootLogger();
            rootLoggerConfig.addAppender(appender, Level.DEBUG, filter);
            config.addLogger(rootLogger.getName(), rootLoggerConfig);

            context.updateLoggers(config);

        }

    }
```